# Template value specialization

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to make a template specialization for a value without additional type?

Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class foo
{
};

template<>
class foo<0>
{
};
```

Comment: Your template expects a type, what sense does a number make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you want to use a nontype template parameter:

```
template<int i>
class foo
{
};

template<>
class foo<0>
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

With the code you show it makes no sense. This, however, is possible:

```
template<int N>
class foo
{
};

template<>
class foo<0>
{
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to try that than to ask the question here. With GCC (g++ 4.6) I am getting

```
temp.cc:7:12: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> class foo'
temp.cc:7:12: error:   expected a type, got '0'
```

So apparently the answer is no

Comment: I said "something like this", that meaning it doesn't work exactly like this:) I need to know if it's possible using other syntax.